# Node app staging fails at Installing App Management stage

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've been trying to push a new build of an app to Bluemix, but staging keeps failing when it's at "Installing App Management" because it can't create regular files and directories due to the disk quota being exceeded.

I've already tried pushing it with "-k 2G", but it it still fails.

Is there any way to find out how or why the disk quota keeps being exceeded? There's no way I'm near using 2GB of disk space.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Log output you are seeing, runtime you are using, etc.

Comment: Some of the output includes: 
`2016-05-31T08:27:27.88-0500 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing App Management
2016-05-31T08:27:32.46-0500 [STG/0]      ERR cp: cannot create regular file ‘/tmp/staged/app/.app-management/handlers/start-strongpm/node_modules/strong-start/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/loopback-connector-sqlite3/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/qs/.npmignore’: Disk quota exceeded`

It goes on for a while. We're using SDK for Node.js.

Comment: If you aren't using app management you could bypass the install by setting `cf set-env myApp BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_INSTALL false`. It normally works even with 1G disk though, so it seems like something else may be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are not uploading your `node_modules` along with your app? You need to add a `.cfignore` file at the root of your app directory to specify files and subdirectories to avoid uploading, [as described here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#exclude), if you are not already.

Comment: I had put node_modules in a .cfignore, but it doesn't seem to be working/helping. Would `node_modules/` the correct format?

Comment: Both should work...can you possibly link to your source code?

Comment: I could; where/how should I link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to npm v3 is a potentinal solution here as it reduces the number of duplicated dependencies.

You can do that in your package.json, for example:

```
"engines": { "npm": "3.x" }
```

Comment: This definitely did the trick the new buildpack https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/06/15/bluemix-node-js-buildpack-update/ installs app managment by default but with npm 2 it reinstalls a bunch of libs and overflows  the disk. Using npm 3 solved it for me !

Answer (score 0):

By design, the CloudFoundry applications on IBM Bluemix are limited to an available diskquota of 2GB (default is 1 GB): usually if a cloud application needs more than a 1GB (even 1GB is a lot for a cloud application...) it should be redesigned according to cloud patterns, breaking down it into microservices, using external storage services if it needs simply static storage (for example ObjectStorage service on Bluemix).
You have also to consider that a cloud application filesystem is a unreliable filesystem, the application itself could be automatically deployed on a different virtual environment without any evidence for the end users.
Even the logs should be collected on external services (routing the log stream) if you need to keep these safe, otherwise they will be reset as soon as the application will be restarted on a different cluster node.

Comment: It's, like, 150MB. I have no idea why or how it's exceeding the disk quota, and it's been like this since Friday. The logs aren't telling me anything helpful, and all I can deduce is something is going wrong at the Installing App Management stage.

Comment: please run from your command line:
# cf apps
or
# cf app [app-name]

It will show the status of your application

Comment: This is what I get: `Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170001, message: Staging error: cannot get instances since staging failed`

Comment: So your application isn't failing during its activities but it fails during staging.
I suppose that you staging phase is making your application structure exceeding the 2GB: could you please share which dependencies are you importing? If you starting source code is of 150 MB but you are importing dependencies for a lot of GBs, it will fail

Comment: Two internal libraries, cfenv, express, react, and react-dom.

We haven't changed any of our dependencies, and none of our builds prior to last Friday failed.

Comment: It doesn't seem an amount of libs requiring > 2GB.
Could you try disabling app management by cf set-env myApp BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_INSTALL false and push it again?

Comment: Disk quota gets exceeded at the following stage now: `Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules`