# Running out of space deploying node.js babel app

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, babeljs

I have a node.js app which uses babel. To get it to build, I changed the build type to npm and added the 'npm run babel' to do the babel step.

However, when it deploys, it runs for a while, and then eventually runs out of disk space:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/tmp/contents410112420/app/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/fn/typed/data-view.js’: No space left on device
```

Help!

Comment: For the record, I increase my disk_quota to 2G but that appeared to have no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548359/node-app-staging-fails-at-installing-app-management-stage

Comment: Nope, not duplicate...

Comment: Can you include your package.json or all the dependencies from package.json in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to npm v3 should resolve the problem as it reduces the number of duplicated dependencies.

You can do that in your package.json, for example:

```
"engines": { "npm": "3.x" }
```

Or switch to node.js v6 and get npm v3 by default:

```
"engines": { "node": "6.x" }
```

Comment: I already had: "engines": {
  "node": ">=6.9.1",
  "npm": ">=3.10.8"
 } in my package.json

Comment: You could also try setting the environment variable BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_INSTALL to "false" if you are not using app management features. That would buy you a little more space.

Comment: You could also try setting the environment variable NODE_MODULES_CACHE to "false" to make sure only the dependencies you currently need are getting pulled in and not anything older.

Comment: Wasn't sure which stage to add those to so added to both, but still get exactly same error.